# divergence theorem for the flux through a surface $\phi$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a surface $\phi(u,v)=(u\cos v,1-u,u\sin v) ; u\in[0,1]; v\in[0,2\pi]$.

I want calculate the flux through $\phi$ of $F(x,y,z)=(z+\arctan y,\frac{x^5}{1+z^2},x^2ze^{y^2}) $

Can I use divergence theorem?

Comment: is $\phi$ a closed surface?  It is not obvious to me that it is.  In fact, I am pretty sure that it isn't.  If it were, you could apply the divergence theorem.    By the way, I don't think this should have the "real-analysis" tag.

Comment: $\phi$ is created by rotation around y-axis of $\gamma(t)=(t,1-t,0)$

Comment: You can apply the divergence theorem, if you seal up the surface with a disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the divergence theorem but you can do this.

$F = G + H\\
G = (z + \tan^{-1}y, \frac {x^5}{1+z^2},0)\\
H= (0,0,x^2ze^{y^2})$

$G$ is a divergence free field.  That means by the implication of Stokes theorem that the flux of $G$ over $\phi$ equals the flux of $G$ over the disk of radius $1$ 
in the $xz$ plane.

The flux of $G = 0$
that means you just need to find the flux of $H$.
That doesn't look particularly easy, but a lot easier than the flux of $F$.

Wait....

you can seal up the bottom of $\phi$ with the disk above.  And apply the divergence theorem.
$$\iiint \operatorname{div} H dV = \iint H d\phi + \iint H dD$$

$$\iint H dD = 0$$

$$\iiint \operatorname{div} H dV = \iint H d\phi$$

Comment: Can I use stokes theorem: $\int_{\Sigma}<rot,v> d\sigma=\int_{\gamma}F_1 dx+F_2 dy+F_3 dz$?

Comment: so I have $\int_{0}^{1} arctan(1-t)-t^5 dt$?

Comment: can you make the explicit computation?

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{(1-u)} u^3cos^2v e^{y^2}\,dy\,du\,dv$  But from what I can see, this does not integrate into elementary functions.